# Remove state for current location

Tags: react-router

Every time I change the route, I send a message through location`s state.
I want to remove that message when componentWillUnmont().

```
`this.context.router.push({
            pathname: '/EmpReferralListView',
            state: {
                message: (typeof message != 'undefined') ? message : ''
            }
    });`
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stuck on a similar problem like I was...This is for react router v4.

What you can do, instead, is hook into the `componentWillMount()` method.

Define the `message` in your component's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.message = '';
}
```

Then your `componentWillMount()` will look like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.message) {
        this.message = this.props.location.state.message;
        this.props.history.replace({
            pathname: this.props.location.pathname,
            state: {}
        });
    }
}
```

The above code will replace the location's state after you've grabbed the message. So you'll want to use `this.message` to display that message moving forward.

Now, you can reference your message during render like so:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.message}</div>
    );
}
```

Your message should clear when the location changes.

I would recommend creating a component specifically for this task which you can then include in any component which you're expecting the message.

Comment: I would have done it like that instead:   ```this.props.history.replace({
            ...this.props.location.pathname,
            state: {}
        });```  in order to keep every single elements